# AJAX firing no_connection(); too early

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have this Google Chrome extension..

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "My extension",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.8.3.min.js", "content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
}
```

popup.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
    <style>
      body {
        min-width:357px;
        overflow-x:hidden;
      }

      img {
        margin:5px;
        border:2px solid black;
        vertical-align:middle;
        width:75px;
        height:75px;
      }
    </style>

    <!-- JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files for security. -->
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="ajax">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js:

```
function start() {
    var reg = false;
    if (window.ActiveXObject){
        reg = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }else {
        reg = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    reg.open("GET","http://www.dr.dk/",true); // Insert a reference of the php page you wanna get instead of yourpage.php
    reg.send(null);
    reg.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (reg.readyState == 4 && reg.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = reg.responseText;
        }else {
            no_connection();
        }
    }
}

function no_connection() {

    var reg = false;
    if (window.ActiveXObject){
        reg = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }else {
        reg = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    reg.open("GET","no_connection.html",true); // Insert a reference of the php page you wanna get instead of yourpage.php
    reg.send(null);
    reg.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (reg.readyState == 4 && reg.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = reg.responseText;
        }else {
            document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = 'An Unknown Error did happened.';
        }
    }
}

start();
```

This just always comes up with the content from no_connection.html, but if I out comment the line:

```
no_connection();
```

From the:

```
function start();
```

Then it works fine, then it shows the content of `http://www.dr.dk/`

How can this happens, when the `no_conncection();` is inside a `if else` statement, how can it overides that then?

Any idea how to fix this issue, as this is getting pretty weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the **reg.onreadystatechange** is a block function, and is gets called every time your state changes. It is therefor being called during the call, as well as after the call. (twice, possibly more)

Also, a sidenote, remember that dr.dk is very furious when someone leeches content from their site, or even just links at them from other sites...

In your else statement, you need to listen specifiaclly on a fail. Suggested structure :

```
request[requestid].onreadystatechange = function() {
  /* This is a slightly confusing part of the script.  We don't wait to hear back from the server before we continue
  with the communicate() function.  It sends the request, and if and when the server gets back to us, whatever's
  specified as request[requestid].onreadystatechange is performed.  So, we have to define .onreadystatechange
  BEFORE we actually make contact with the server.  If you're reading this and trying to learn how it works,
  you may want to take a glance at the last part of the communicate() function first, and then come back here. */
  try {
   /* We use try and catch because Javascript will give an error when we try to access request[requestid].status if the
   server is down or if the user navigates away from the page. */
   if (request[requestid].readyState == 4 && request[requestid].status == 200) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeout[requestid]);
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    /* 4 = The AJAX Request is complete; 200 = The HTTP server found the data we needed and was able to send it to us. */
    eval(request[requestid].responseText);
    } else if (request[requestid].readyState == 4 && request[requestid].status != 200) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeout[requestid]);
    if (failure) eval(failure);
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    alert ('Error ' + request[requestid].status + ':  Server error.  If you entered data, it may or may not have been saved.  Please contact your systems administrator.');
    }
   } catch(e) {
   window.clearTimeout(timeout[requestid]);
   document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
   if (failure) eval(failure);
   alert ('Error:  Unable to communicate with server.  Please contact your systems administrator.  You may want to try again in a few minutes to see if the problem fixes itself. \n\n(Either the server was down, the communication was interrupted, or there was an error in the data sent by the server.)\n' + e + '\n\n' + request[requestid].responseText);
   }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Nils.
dr.dk is just a example, before I attempt to make my own API to get content from.

But how would I make it works for me then, sorry, but Im new to Javascript.

Comment: Np. I have added a suggested structure to my answer post.

Comment: Thanks, but I just get the following error `request is not defined`, Should I still include:
`var request = false; if (window.ActiveXObject){ request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }else { request = new XMLHttpRequest(); }`

Comment: Have you changed to using request[requestid] instead of just using "reg" ?

Comment: Oh. Thanks. My bad. What should I do with the `[requestid]`?

Comment: its an array key, you can define it any way you want really.